# Retrieve AJAX (XHR) infos from a dynamic website in C#

Tags: c#, ajax, xmlhttprequest, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to create an app using C# to retrieve my data cap infos from my ISP site. The page is [this one](http://internet.tre.it/) but I suspect it can't be accessed from outside their network so if anyone needs more information just ask.

The page loads through AJAX the remaining traffic quota and displays it in the page after it's loaded. Right now I already have a working app using HtmlAgilityPack but it pretty hideous considering I'm using a WebBrowser control to load the page in background, wait for five seconds, parse the page's HTML with the library and see if it finds the necessary HTML string; if not the timer resets and repeats itself until the javascript has done its thing and loaded the data cap infos.

I want to somehow replicate what the webpage does and call the server and ask directly for the infos without creating a web browser instance in background and waiting for the infos to load.

Is it possible?

**URL** http://internet.tre.it/calls/checkMSISDN.aspx?g=2518607185932962118&h=UItDOr88/CtwONsfqfLgblVuTAysHYKc3kh6mLgiX0He49TU0I9lc56O8mWVhxzd3yFUDFF08P/Ng/5cg2nLtefFfjUIBq/QNQalmmSnKkQ=&mc=22299&acid=0&_=1541582209456

**Headers**

```
Host: internet.tre.it
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://internet.tre.it/
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: cookiesAccepted=1; _iub_cs-160673=%7B%22id%22%3A160673%2C%22consent%22%3Atrue%2C%22timestamp%22%3A%222018-04-16T15%3A42%3A10.978Z%22%2C%22version%22%3A%220.13.22%22%7D; ASP.NET_SessionId=n2wz2brfaepfj2klo0nqfwaw; pageVisit=c73074b54dbe40d49a715aeb9a0f4ea8; 148162__148162_d32646f682e342dba303540b0f10dac1=1
```

**Response**

[Album of the JSON response.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOYGj.jpg) (I blacked out those two lines because they were respectively my own name and my phone number)

Comment: It looks like the server is returning json. Can you include a screenshot of the response (it's the tab next to 'headers'). That would help.

Comment: Done adding an album of the response. As you can see there's a lot to unpack because many of the informations given back are ads displayed in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response being a json string, I recommend the following :

- Write code to download the json string from the URL. See for instance
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11891101/4180382
- Copy the whole json string from your F12 response tab
- In Visual Studio create a new class file
- Click Edit > Paste special > Paste Json as classes.
- In your code you will need the name of the first class that you pasted. It is the parent class. I would say it is 'Banners', but verify.
- `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < Banners>(downloadedJson);`
- Now you can loop through the Menu array to extract all of the info you need.

And you are done! If all the info is in the json, no need to use HtmlAgilityPack. Let me know how you fare.

Comment: Going to try this is the evening. Indeed if it works I won’t need Agility anymore. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I tried what you suggested @Ole EH Dufour and with the exception of the first part everything seems to work. If I hardcode the JSON response I managed to extract the data I needed but when I tried to get the JSON through the suggested method it kept returning nothing. I think it has to do with the fact the parameters seems to change from reload to reload of the page (the part after `http://internet.tre.it/calls/checkMSISDN.aspx`) or the fact I'm trying to directly download the page instead of doing a GET request.

Comment: @nicktheone Yes you need to authenticate. You can do that using HtmlAgilityPack or Selenium. With F12 you can monitor network traffic that you will need to emulate using one of those tools.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for although I couldn't manage to reverse the private API I was trying to access. Had it been a public API it'd have been the solution for my issue.

Comment: Even logging on can be automated. See for ex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44172427/selenium-webdriver-automated-login

Comment: Thanks for the tip but the page doesn't require an authentication based on a username and password but simply checks if you're connected to their network (mobile operator) and if yes it sends the authetication through the GET request with authentication parameters based on an alghoritm I can't understand.